# Viewing php echo after a POST with REST client in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm using a rest client in chrome to manually post data. In the php file, I echo a value when this post is read. Where can I view the echo'ed data in the dev tools on chrome?

Comment: have you tried the Network tab?

Comment: yea, nothing there. The preview tab just shows the page javascript

Comment: You should check the Response tab. Isn't that what you want to see?

Comment: What REST client are you using?

Comment: chrome has a "simple rest client" add on

Comment: If you are reffering to this addon https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb, then I see it shows the request response. If this is not what you're using you might want to consider using it.

Comment: it is that app. the response is js code as well

Comment: Then the problem is on the server. What data type are you expecting back from the server JSON, XML?